# Can't implement OnCheckedChangeListener?

Tags: java, android, interface

I've a question.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyCheckBox extends CheckBox implements OnCheckedChangeListener {



public MyCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

But "onCheckedChangeListener" can't be implemented ( eclipse marks as red squiggly line). It says "Import onCheckedChangeListener", I'm clicking but nothing happens.

Is this eclipse bug or something else?

Comment: It could be that you imported OnCheckedChangeListener from another library where it is an (abstract) class, not an interface. Or it could indeed by an eclipse bug. Did you try restarting eclipse?

Comment: I've restared eclipse. Also I've tried to create new project just for this case, and it's the same. However, I tried with OnClickListener, and it works. But not with onCheckedChangeListener..

hmm

Comment: make sure eclipse is importing the correct import. OnCheckedChangeListener is in radio group and check box. The onClickListener is defined in View, that's why it is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OnCheckedChangeListener` is for radio group. 
So you need to implement `android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` for CheckBox

Comment: Good lord. I feel like a dumbass now. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have imported:

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

Problem could be here. Also tap `CTRL+SHIFT+O` that will clean your imports and add missing imports as well.

If it won't work, restart Eclipse and clean your project. If it still doesn't  work, reinstall Eclipse completely.